# Retrieving data from same table where multiple columns match in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have a table with data where in a situation one rows' id becomes another rows reference id. The table is as below.

[image]

I tried to retrieve data as below,

```
select * from table1 t where t.id = t.reference_id
```

but it returns empty table.

Comment: you should try a self join..

Comment: like this:- select * from table1 inner join table1 h on t.id = t.reference_id

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. Formatted text, please! (I.e. no images....)

Answer (score 3):

Try a self join like :

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table1 t2 on t1.id = t2.reference_id
```